# How to get string value from a database using SQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I need to have a table representation of items in a database. The FRUIT table has four values: ID, TYPE, PRICE, DESCRIPTION. I want a loop to iterate over each item in the FRUIT table and put it in a table. This is what I have so far:

```
echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Type</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
$invSize = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FRUIT;");
for ($count = 0; $count < $invSize; ++$count){
        $type = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TYPE FROM FRUIT WHERE ID = $count;");
        $price = $dbh->prepare("SELECT PRICE FROM FRUIT WHERE ID = $count;");
    $desc = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM FRUIT WHERE ID = $count;");
    echo "<tr><td>", $type, "</td><td>", $price, "</td><td>", $desc, "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

When I run the code on the server, it displays the first row of the table (the headings), then in the second row in the first cell, this error message is shown:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string.
```

Any idea why this is, and what I could do to fix it?

Comment: why is your concatenation `,` instead or `.`? is that a typo?

Comment: You cannot use `PDOStatement`s like strings or numbers. See [the documentation](http://dk1.php.net/pdostatement). You are also using prepared statements incorrectly.

Comment: your code is incomplete, your trying to concatenate your strings to `$db->prepare()` which returns an object. try to visit [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), it has an example on how to use it properly